# Using Yule Walker equations for ACF and PACF

Tags: time-series

When using Using Yule Walker equations for getting ACF and PACF, is it essential that the time series has to be stationary? In other words, do we really need Box-Cox transformations before we use Yule Walker for ACF and PACF

Thanks,
Ratheen

Answer (score 3):

You are using method of moments estimators for the population ACF and PACF. These sample estimates or SPACF and SACF always can be calculated but are they really consistent estimates for the population if their population counterparts diverge as time index increases?

So answer is that series must be stationary.